# What is the difference between iterator and &iterator?

Tags: c++

```
    vector<int> A = {1, 2, 3};
    
    //case 1
    for(auto it : A){
        it = 0;
    }
    
    print(A) //OUTPUT -> 1, 2, 3
    
    //case 2
    for(auto &it : A){
        it = 0;
    }
    
    print(A) //OUTPUT -> 0, 0, 0
```

How are 'it' and '&it' different? How exactly are iterator and &iterator working?

Comment: `auto it : A` make a copy of each element. `auto &it : A` references each element. So in the 1st loop `it = 0;` assigns to the copy, and in the 2nd `it = 0;` assigns (via the reference) to the element in the vector.  Note that in both cases `it` is not an iterator.

Comment: None of the it variables in your example is an iterator!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

##### Case 1

The `auto` keyword(without the use of `&`) infers a non-reference type. This means in your case 1, `auto` infers `it` to be of type `int`. This is a non-reference type, meaning that the values from the `std::vector` will get copied into the loop variable `it`, which in turn means that any changes made to `it` will not be reflected in the `std::vector` itself.

##### Case 2

In case 2, however, due to the use of `&` in `auto`, the loop variable `it` is of type `int&` which is a reference type and any change you make on `it` will be reflected on the original vector.

Answer (score 0):

When using `&` for the type in a foreach loop, the loop will go over references to the items in the vector.

I might be more readable if you write the seconds loop as:

```
    for(auto& it : A){
        it = 0;
    }
```

And then it means that the element of type `auto` will be a reference to the element in `A`.

When not using `&`, each element is copied in each iteration, so when you assign to it, it has no effect on the original vector.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `auto` in C++11 and later, the compiler has to deduce the type.
According to the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto):

> type is deduced using the rules for [template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Other_contexts).

This means that qualifiers like `const` and `volatile`, as well as being a pointer or a refernce, are not a part of the deduced type. In other words the deduced type will be the basic type of the expression assigned to the `auto` variable, without `const`,`volatile` or pointer/reference indirection.

Example: If you have a function like:

```
A & GetA() { ... }
```

You can use it in several ways.
In all of them `auto` will be deduced as `A`, but the type of `a` will be different:

```
auto a = GetA();         // The type of `a` will be `A`, and a copy will be made.
auto & a = GetA();       // The type of `a` will be `A&`. No copy will be made.
auto const & a = GetA(); // The type of `a` will be `A const&`. No copy will be made and the compiler will verify you do not modify the referenced object.
// etc.
```

Aplying this principle to your case:

1. `for(auto it : A)` :
   `auto` will be deduced as `int` and this will be the type of `it`. Therefore a copy will be made of the elements in `A` and placed into `it`. No modification of the element copy will affect the original vector.
2. `for(auto & it : A)` :
   `auto` will still be deduced as `int`, but `it` will be of type `int&`. Therefore no copy will be made, rather we'll get a reference to the vector element. This is why the code was able to modify the vector.

On a side note: using a range based loop (like you do), means that the variable of the loop will be assigned to the actual elements (or their refernce of course) in the collection. This is actually **not** an iterator, so using `it` as a variable name is misleadsing. Better to use e.g. `a` in your case.